# What is XML doc-based IntelliSense supposed to look like?

Tags: visual-c++, intellisense

I have added function documentation in the style prescribed by Visual Studio:

```
/** 
    <summary>MAIN entry point</summary>
    <param name='spreadsheetFileName'>Name of Excel XLS spreadsheet file</param>
    <param name='p'>ExploVent parameters excerpted from spreadsheet</param>
    <returns>True if successful, False if couldn't open file</returns>

*/
bool openSpreadsheet(const char *spreadsheetFileName, vector <cEVparams> &p)
{ ...
}
```

My project is set for XML Documentation & IntelliSense:

```
Properties ➔ C/C++ ➔ Output Files ➔ Generate XML Documentation Files ➔ Yes
```

- The .SDF (ex-NCB) file has been deleted & re-generated
- I'm using STDAFX.H for pre-compiled headers
- The XML Documentation File *is* being created from the XCDs. I can see my function documentation in the XML.
- This is an VS2010 MFC project, not .NET

However, when I display the information associated with the function, it is no different than the IntelliSense I got before I added the fancy XML markup:.

Here is what I see when pressing Ctrl-K, Ctrl-I:

[image]

Here is Ctrl-J:

[image]

Curiously, Ctrl-Shift-Space does nothing.

Is this as good as it gets? I would expect my <summary> and <param> tags to be more clearly formatted.

Am I missing something? What does *your* XML-based IntelliSense look like?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is a Visual Studio version issue. It works in VS 2013 and VS 2015, but not in VS 2010. Also it works better for C# than C++.

Thank you to Ori and Vivek from Upwork.com